# Razorpay Error - {"code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR","description":"ay_order_id is not a valid id"}

Tags: android, razorpay

I'm implement `Razorpay` with `PaymentResultWithDataListener`. Actually i need `order_id` and `signature` so i use `PaymentResultWithDataListener` not used `PaymentResultListener` because there are no option to get `order_id` and `signature`. And I have follow these links

https://docs.razorpay.com/v1/page/orders#verifying-the-signature

https://razorpay.com/mobile/

https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-android-sample-app

But not getting any solution.

**Menifest File**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.razorpay.ApiKey"
    android:value="rzp_test_PLbERPkkqGZkOF" />
```

**build.gradle**

```
api 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.4'
```

I got an error

```
{"code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR","description":"ay_order_id is not a valid id"}
```

I am trying with this code

```
public class CheckoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, PaymentResultWithDataListener {
    private static final String TAG = CheckoutActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    Button mCheckOutView;

    String OrderId = "";
    String signature = "";
    String order_id = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_method);

        Checkout.preload(getApplicationContext());

        mCheckOutView = findViewById(R.id.check_out);

        mCheckOutView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mCheckOutView) {
            startPayment();
        }
    }

    public void startPayment() {
        /*
          You need to pass current activity in order to let Razorpay create CheckoutActivity
         */
        final Activity activity = this;

        final Checkout co = new Checkout();

        try {
            JSONObject options = new JSONObject();
            options.put("name","Test");
            options.put("description", getString(R.string.app_name));
            options.put("key", getString(R.string.api_key));
            options.put("order_id","razorpay_order_id");
            options.put("signature","razorpay_signature");

            options.put("currency", "INR");
            options.put("amount", 100);

            JSONObject preFill = new JSONObject();
            preFill.put("email", "test@gmail.com");
            preFill.put("contact", "9999999999");

            options.put("prefill", preFill);

            JSONObject notesData=new JSONObject();
            notesData.put("Order Id","order123");
            notesData.put("address","Test Address");

            options.put("notes", notesData);

            JSONObject theme=new JSONObject();
            theme.put("color","#738598");
            theme.put("emi_mode",true);

            options.put("theme", theme);

            co.open(activity, options);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Error in payment: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentSuccess(String s, PaymentData paymentData) {
        String paymentId = paymentData.getPaymentId();
        String signature = paymentData.getSignature();  // got null
        String orderId = paymentData.getOrderId();      // got null
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentError(int i, String s, PaymentData paymentData) {
        Log.e(TAG,s);  //error {"code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR","description":"ay_order_id is not a valid id"}
    }
}
```

If i remove these 2 lines then this error not comes.

```
options.put("order_id","razorpay_order_id");
options.put("signature","razorpay_signature");
```

But `paymentData.getSignature()` and `paymentData.getOrderId()` is `null`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is your id?

Comment: @ManojPerumarath means?

Comment: razorpay_order_id is value & order_id is key

Comment: Actually these key & value are provided by razerpay support team

Comment: {“code”:“BAD_REQUEST_ERROR”,“description”:“ay_order_id is not a valid id”}

Answer (score 2):

```
options.put("order_id","**razorpay_order_id**");
```

you need to generate this order_id from **razorpay Order_ID API**, only after this **order_id** which comes as a response from the API you would be able to process smoothly. After getting this Order_id from API, send it in above code in value (in place of *razorpay_order_id*)

```
options.put("signature","razorpay_signature");
```

This is not required in request. This will be generated at your server and will be used when a response is received in `PaymentResultWithDataListener` function. Read Signature generation method in official Documentation here : https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/android-integration/standard/

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs, by the time you start the checkout, you get the `order_id` when the merchant's backend starts an order with the RazorPay backend.
See the diagram [here](https://docs.razorpay.com/v1/page/orders)`.

As for the signature, according with the docs that's not something you put but something that comes from server responses and which you have to validate on your end. Check [this](https://razorpay.com/docs/webhooks/integrations/)